# Self-hosted site based on HttpListener -- how to handle authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, security, httplistener, self-hosting

If you are building a self-hosted web page around `HttpListener`, how can you handle authentication in a secure way? I don't want to use Basic Authentication because it passes credentials as clear text. I know that digest is another option,

```
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(url);
        listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest; 
        listener.Start();
```

Is it secure enough and what are the standard / best practices for actually grabbing the username/password and authenticating them?

In this situation there is no web.config or hosting environment by default.

Comment: best practice would be to use HTTPS/SSL. Are you avoiding IIS and making your own web server like component? Can I ask why just for curiositi? :)

Comment: I am working on a heavily event-driven and real-time web app (imagine a chat server but with more functionality), using reactive extensions and an event-loop (like how node.js works). Maybe I will integrate it into IIS somehow at some point, but for now its just a bare bones project. As far as using SSL that is configurable with HttpListener, but what about handling user credentials?

Comment: It is easy to imagine why though: an app that requires no IIS, like WinForms app, that can expose a web interface, just so that you can access the app using a web browser.

Comment: `I don't want to use Basic Authentication because it passes credentials as clear text`. This is not a problem if you use `https`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using authentication with HttpListener means having Windows do your authentication for you using its built-in authentication system (i.e. ActiveDirectory). This means for digest authentication you need to create domain accounts for your users. Is this what you were intending? If you want to do your own custom authentication, that's a more complicated matter. I won't  go into how to do that unless you say that's what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. I am intending on using digest most likely, at least for now. I was just concerned about whether it is secure enough. Do you know of any links that explain how to use Digest authentication + active directory? Or does digest do that out of the box?

Comment: Out of the box. What roughly happens is if you set up the HttpListener and do not allow anonymous authentication, the HttpListener will return a 401 to unauthenticated users and the headers will start the authentication protocol. The browser will then pop-up a log in dialog. The user enters credentials. The server will try to authenticate the user using ActiveDirectory. The credentials will have to be valid and the account will need whichever permissions are required to be logged on this way (I don't recall offhand which permissions are required but it's documented somewhere.)

Comment: Your code doesn't see the request at all until the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider implementing support for claimsbased security. You would have to handle security tokens, but the actual user authentication can be "outsourced" to external identity providers.

You could probably leverage Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) for handling most of the work.